# Is there a way of show the FB dialog and call my own method on Post?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm developing an iOS app that needs to post to the user facebook timeline. I have already asked permissions to publish and everything is working fine.

I want to publish doing the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"www.google.com.ar", @"link",
                                   @"http://myimage.pn", @"picture",
                                   @"Test", @"name",
                                   @"location", @"caption",
                                   @"test.",@"description",
                                   @"message to show",@"message",
                                   nil];

[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
 parameters:postParams
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {

}
```

But I want the user to be able to personalize the "message" and to personalize it I want to show something similar to this:

[image]

And when the user pushes the Post I want to grab the text the user posted and add it to my "message" dictionary and after that do the `FBRequestConnection`

Anyone knows if this is possible at all??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The native share dialog doesn't support OpenGraph and you cannot modify the contents of it before sending them to Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/#ios6sharesheet

Comment: That is to say, you'd need to build your own, or use the Facebook SDK share dialog instead.

Comment: Facebook SDK share dialog? I'm checking that!!

Comment: Yep, see this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/#sharedialog

Comment: Thanks dude! I spent hours with this and it wasn't that hard!